# How do I get RegistrationBuilder to actually work?

Tags: c#, .net, mef

Over the years, I've used MEF on several projects and today I discovered, after reading these articles:

[Managed Extensibility Framework Improvements in .NET 4.5](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/02/12/mef-convention-model.aspx)
and
[MEF in .NET 4.5](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/488513/MEF-in-NET)

that in .NET 4.5 Microsoft added some cool features to MEF2; like the RegistrationBuilder. However I couldn't, for the life of me, get the following very simple example to work.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
    }

    public Program()
    {
        var conventions = new RegistrationBuilder();
        conventions.ForType<Person>().Export();
        conventions.ForType<Program>().ImportProperty(p => p.Person);

        var category = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var container = new CompositionContainer(category, CompositionOptions.DisableSilentRejection);

        container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this, conventions);
    }

    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

From what I read, it looks like it should just work, but it doesn't. To verify that it should work, I added the [Export] attribute to Person

```
[Export]
public class Person {...}
```

and the [Import] attribute to the Program.Person property

```
[Import]
public Person Person { get; set; }
```

And it worked! Okay good, but why wouldn't it work when I tried using just the RegistrationBuilder class?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**

The conventions variable **must** be added to both the catalog and the SatisfyImportsOnce function!

Like so:

```
var category = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), conventions);
var container = new CompositionContainer(category, CompositionOptions.DisableSilentRejection);

container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this, conventions);
```

Hope this helps.